# Can venomous snakes be determined by these pupil, nostril and scale patterns?

Tags: physiology, zoology, india, toxicology

This image was recently shared by an Australian Facebook friend:

> [image: Diagram of snakes: A little education never hurts... Poisonous: Elliptical pupil nostril. pit. ]Scales on underside of tail in single row. Non-Poisonous: Round Pupil. Nostril. No pit. Scales on underside of tail in double-row.]

The source appears to be [a Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=443173995873142&set=a.120249081498970.1073741827.100005416359553&type=3&permPage=1) of a man from India with a staggering 380,000 shares from around the world!

There are many different species of venomous snakes (and I assume that they mean [venomous, not poisonous](http://www.snake-removal.com/poisonous-vs-venomous.html)) and I struggle to see how this could be true.

Is it true? Is it true just for snakes in India?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69626/discussion-on-question-by-oddthinking-can-venomous-snakes-be-determined-by-these).

Answer (score 61):

No, this is not true. Not even for just India, as Indian cobra (Naja naja) has round pupils and subcaudal (tail) scales are divided. There is also no pit visible. It is venomous species of snake.

This answer assumes, that author means venomous snakes instead of poisonous, as this is common mistake. Also, Wikipedia should have enough credibility for this answer:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_cobra

Comment: There are actual poisonous snakes such as the [*Rhabophis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhabdophis). However, it shouldn't be poisonous according to the claim.

Comment: It is even worse, the snake that causes the most bites/deaths in india Russells Viper https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_viper does not have pits as it is not a Pit Viper https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pit_viper.

Comment: I suspect the diagram was intended for use in North America, where the common venomous snakes (the [pit vipers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pit_viper)) match the description quite well.

Comment: IMHO the venomous vs. poisonous "mistake" is so common in regular English usage that it is the people who insist the English language has a hard difference in meaning between the two who are in error.

Comment: @T.E.D. The problem with that opinion now becomes how to distinguish poisonous snakes from venomous snakes?

Comment: @slebetman - My guess would be we have never really required that distinction because not a lot of English speakers are in the habit of eating snakes.

Comment: If you bite it and you die, its poisonous. If it bites you and you die, its venomous. If it bites you, and it dies, you're Chuck Norris.

Answer (score 26):

... maybe a bit more education hurts even less... but the answer is still **no**.

- So to me the description with pits and slit pupils (and also the head drawing) looks like indicating **pit vipers**. I don't knot about their tail scales, though (and it doesn't seem very practial to me to check...). Pit vipers are venomous.
- But there are lots of venomous snakes without pits and with round pupils. E.g. the cobras were mentioned already in another answer.

---

- There are about [3500 species of snakes](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systematik_der_Schlangen).
- About 1/4 of them are venomous. Venomous species of snakes are *not* concentrated in a particular branch of the snake taxonomy. [[Wiki venomous snake]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venomous_snake#Taxonomy)
- But there are several families of snakes where all species are venomous: Elapidae, Viperidae and Atractaspidinae. There are other Families with  venomous and non-venomous species.
- One family of venomous snakes are the [vipers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viperidae).

  - > [The great majority [of vipers] have vertically elliptical, or **slit-shaped, pupils**.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viperidae)
  - **pits**: the sub-family of [pit vipers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pit_viper) has them.
    But then, also many Pythons and Boas (both non-venomous families of snakes) have similar pits.
  - If the drawing in question is trying to distinguish (pit) vipers from other snakes, they are missing the rather distinctive head shape that many vipers have.
- **scales** [[Wiki Snake scale]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_scale):

  > Scales do not play an important role in distinguishing between the families but are important at generic and specific level.
  >   [...]
  >
  > There is no simple way of differentiating a venomous snake from a non-venomous one merely by using a scale character.

  - It is also not so very practical:

    > Distinguishing by using scale diagrams whether a snake is venomous or not in the field cannot be done in the case of uncaught specimens
  - In certain regions, distinguishing by scales may work:

    > In certain regions, presence or absence of certain scales may be a quick way to distinguish non-venomous and venomous snakes, but used with care and knowledge of exceptions. For example, in Myanmar, the presence or absence of loreal scales can be used to distinguish between relatively harmless Colubrids and lethally venomous Elapids.

  Note though that this distinction tries to use scale patterns on the head, not below the tail.

  - Back to the vipers, they typically have keeled scales (i.e. with a ridge)
  - In my region (Germany), there are only 2 species of venomous snakes, both vipers ([aspis viper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipera_aspis) and [common European viper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipera_berus)) but not pit vipers, and according to the respective Wiki pages they have paired scales on the lower side of the tail... => 2:1 failure of suggested rule.
    But then, the most common "snaky" animal we have isn't even a snake (neither venomous): [image: slowworm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anguis_fragilis)

Comment: Now you had me look it up and I found out that the English term is not "blind-sneaky" ;)

Comment: After dozens enconters with snakes, scorpions, spiders and venous/poisonous fish I found the little criters actually knows they are dangerous (sure it's a importat part in they behaviour) so I follow a rule of thumb: 1. If it run away from you just be cautions to not step in it. 2. if it seems to ignore you or just is no moving be extremely cautious. 3. If it attacks you run like hell

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I had to look up the "slowworm" as well ;-)

Comment: @jean: Most wild animals actually follow more or less the same rule of thumb when they encounter an unfamiliar creature. This can sometimes lead to funny results like, say, a naïve housecat being scared of an overconfident mouse. It also makes running away from an animal yourself a bad idea in most cases, since it tells the creature you're facing that you're safe to chase (and since you're neither fast enough nor agile enough to *actually* run away from most things that could hurt you). Usually, option #2 (back off slowly, stand your ground if approached) is what you should aim for.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Not quite really. First I refering to snakes and venous things and can extend it to nasty critters like wolverines and if it attacks you must run or fight anyway. Note I cannot give my back to big felines, they really have this thing to jump in anything giving the back to them. I growth in a place overrun by snakes and learned how to handle them if necessary, even killed dozens (venous) in my backyard (fear of accidents with my family and pets). This was a generic advice.

Answer (score 22):

**That is a diagram for identifying [pit vipers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pit_viper).** There are many, many venomous snakes in the world, including I believe all of the most deadly ones, that are not pit vipers.

The advice is particularly unfortunate for Australia, as **not a single one of [Australia's 10 most dangerous snakes](http://www.australiangeographic.com.au/topics/science-environment/2012/07/australias-10-most-dangerous-snakes/) are pit vipers.** All 10 are instead [elapids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elapidae).

**The origin of this graphic is almost certainly English-speaking North America**. For much, if not all of that area, the only venomous wild snakes are pit vipers. As a kid in Oklahoma I was given these exact instructions verbally for identifying poisonous snakes<sup>*</sup>. This simplification is possible in the USA because the only venomous snake in the continental USA that isn't a pit viper is the coral snake, whose range is limited to the Southeast, is rarely seen even there, and is generally not aggressive.

[image]

---

<sup>* - I am repeating the term that was used at the time for these snakes when said people were talking about them. I know its fashionable these days to maintain that "poisonous" doesn't really mean that. For that reason when I'm trying to be technical I'll instead use "venomous". But consider that language is arrived at by consensus, not dictate. If you have to explain to everyone you meet what a word means, you should consider the possibility that it isn't they who are wrong.</sup>

Comment: Re: terminology - we've [just been having that discussion](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4101/should-standard-or-non-standard-vocabulary-take-precedent-neither) on Meta.

Answer (score -2):

As answers state, these are signs for *some* snakes in *some* parts of the world.

The only sign I know that is said to be generally applicable, is a **broadening / widening of the head around the side of the skull** (as if seen from above) - because poison glands and (for those snakes which have them) additional muscles and anchor points to control fang movement and compress the glands to send venom into the duct/groove in the tooth and thereby into the target can tend to shape the head.

In other words try looking at venomous vs. nonvenomous snake heads from above, rather than from the side, and see if that helps.

I don't know how universal that is, but it might stand a chance of being helpful.

Or perhaps it's unreliable as well.